# Multiple Domains for the same Meteor App - how to get the URL

Tags: meteor, nginx

I need to serve a meteor-app on several domains (e.g. customer1.com and customer2.com) and based upon which domain it runs on, it should serve different css files and change its behaviour a little.

I use nginx as a proxy to forward all incoming traffic (except for some special subdomains) to this webapp.

(how) is it possible to get the URL, over which the app is accessed inside of meteor?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `iron-router` you can get the host from the request object

```
Router.route('/testHost', function() {
  this.response.end(this.request.headers.host);
  //the page will print out something like 127.0.0.1:3000 
}, {where: 'server'});
```